# if using table rows inline-editable in mobile view the best practice as Ux

Tags: mobile, data-tables, inline-edit

I am working on a data table with many columns, and I depend on inline editing when the user double click the row. currently, I am working on a responsive version for this table to be viewed on mobile, and back to some of the time limation using a horizontal scrollable table is required on the mobile version. my inquiry is in this case using inline edit on mobile is ok or depends on the modal popup.

Comment: Once they have selected the line, **why** does it still need to be presented horizontally? Wouldn't a vertical list of the "columns" be much more useful?

Comment: it back to the huge number of columns and if viewed vertically it can take the whole mobile screen.

Answer (score 1):

"Editing a table on mobile can be complex, but it's entirely feasible.

If the task involves editing a single cell in the table, I would recommend implementing a long-press indication on the cell. This feature typically doesn't conflict with the scroll function. It's essential, however, to clarify for the development team that the long-press function should only apply when the table is in a static mode, not during scrolling.

If the goal is to edit an entire row in the table, and either cell-by-cell editing isn't an option or there are too many cells to edit individually, I might suggest adding an edit control feature. This could involve a popup or redirecting to a separate screen that handles the table edits. I recommend looking at how Notion did it amazing.

Good Luck :)

[image]